# mod_rewrite redirect is appending url args I dont want

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, seo

I have a lot of old urls that I need to redirect.  The site works by hitting an `index.php?url=whatever` via a mod_rewrite rule.  However, I dont want the user to see the arg in the case of a redirect:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^clients_whatever1\.html$   /  [R]
    RewriteRule  ^clients_whatever2\.html$   /client-list/whatever2  [R]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
```

So in the case of:

`(the domain)/clients_whatever2.html`

they are being redirected to:

`(the domain)/client-list/whatever2?url=/client-list/whatever2`

but it should simply read as:

`(the domain)/client-list/whatever2`

How to do the redirect so that it shows up in the browser url as any other request (for a non-redirect)?

Answer (score 0):

Append a `?` to the rule target to drop the original query string params i.e.

```
RewriteRule ^clients_whatever1\.html$   /?  [R,L]
RewriteRule  ^clients_whatever2\.html$   /client-list/whatever2?  [R,L]
```

Comment: what I mean is that a url entered as http://example.com/clients_whatever2.html is being transformed into http://example.com/client-list/whatever2?url=/client-list/whatever  -- even with your '?' appended

Comment: @DanielSmith try adding the `L` to stop processing as above

Comment: @UlrichPalha Can you please elaborate?